# If loop inside for loop to filter line segments Micropython on OpenMV cam

Tags: python, micropython

I am using a OpenMV cam H7 to try to convert an analogue gauge to digital representation. Screen scraping is a term sometimes used. To that end, the supplied "find_line_segments" sample Micropython code below returns {x1, y1, x2, y2, length, magnitude, theta, rho}. I want to filter what shows on screen based on size. Any conditional logic I add fails. Any pointers, would be much appreciated!

```
# Find Line Segments Example
#
# This example shows off how to find line segments in the image. For each line object
# found in the image a line object is returned which includes the line's rotation.

# find_line_segments() finds finite length lines (but is slow).
# Use find_line_segments() to find non-infinite lines (and is fast).

enable_lens_corr = False # turn on for straighter lines...

import sensor, image, time

sensor.reset()
sensor.set_pixformat(sensor.RGB565) # grayscale is faster
sensor.set_framesize(sensor.QQVGA)
sensor.skip_frames(time = 2000)
clock = time.clock()



# All lines also have `x1()`, `y1()`, `x2()`, and `y2()` methods to get their end-    points
# and a `line()` method to get all the above as one 4 value tuple for `draw_line()`.

while(True): 
    clock.tick()
    img = sensor.snapshot()
    if enable_lens_corr: img.lens_corr(1.8) # for 2.8mm lens...

# `merge_distance` controls the merging of nearby lines. At 0 (the default), no
# merging is done. At 1, any line 1 pixel away from another is merged... and so
# on as you increase this value. You may wish to merge lines as line segment
# detection produces a lot of line segment results.

# `max_theta_diff` controls the maximum amount of rotation difference between
# any two lines about to be merged. The default setting allows for 15 degrees.

for l in img.find_line_segments(merge_distance = 0, max_theta_diff = 5):
# This is where I am inserting my if conditional statements.
    img.draw_line(l.line(), color = (255, 0, 0))
    
    print(l)
    
   

print("FPS %f" % clock.fps())
```

Comment: What attribute do you want to filter on? What threshold value? What have you tried that failed? How did it fail?

Comment: Good day Adam, I want to filter for "length" for now, I will also require the "theta" and "rho" when I get the program picking out the right gauge hands. The fourth line from the bottom is where I have inserted "if l.line([5]) > 25" My lack of python experience is showing. Thanks for the comment, I get "Syntax Error: invalid syntax" error.

Comment: Check the spec for a listing of the attribute [names] of each line_segment (or use ‘print(dir(line_segment))’). You’ll probably want something like ‘if l.length > 25: [...]’

Comment: Thank you for the interest! The spec for the image library is :